# Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::getContent()

Tags: laravel

So I just start using Laravel and Orchid yesterday...
and now I have this problem

I want to create a data page to all posts

So I create the layout: PostListLayout

class PostListLayout extends Table
{

```
    public $target = 'posts';

    /**
     * @return TD[]
     */
    public function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            TD::make('title', 'Title')
                ->render(function (Post $post) {
                    return Link::make($post->title)
                        ->route('platform.post.edit', $post);
                }),

            TD::make('created_at', 'Created'),
            TD::make('updated_at', 'Last edit'),
        ];
    }
}
```

and after that I defined the table layer, we return to the view screen

```
class PostListScreen extends Screen
{
    /**
     * Display header name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name = 'Blog post';

    /**
     * Display header description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $description = 'All blog posts';

    /**
     * Query data.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function query(): array
    {
        return [
            'posts' => Post::paginate()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Button commands.
     *
     * @return Link[]
     */
    public function commandBar(): array
    {
        return [
            Link::make('Create new')
                ->icon('pencil')
                ->route('platform.post.edit')
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Views.
     *
     * @return Layout[]
     */
    public function layout(): array
    {
        return [
            PostListLayout::class
        ];
    }
}
```

but In the end I get this error page:

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::getContent() (View: C:\Users\KHARYA\Desktop\ORCHID\orchid-project\vendor\orchid\platform\resources\views\layouts\table.blade.php)
```

Comment: There are no calls to `Post::getContent()` in this code, nor is the `Post` model shown. Presumably you haven't defined this method before trying to use it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

in app\Models\Posts.php

```
class Posts extends Model {use AsMultiSource ...}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Orchid\Screen\AsSource` Trait as seen in [Orchid documentation](https://orchid.software/en/docs/screens/#querying-data) to fix this error.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Orchid\Screen\AsSource;

class Posts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, AsSource;
}
```